# Can you dissolve iodine without potassium iodide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions

I don't have a sufficient amount of potassium iodide, so I wanted to know if there is other way which I can use to dissolve iodine without using potassium iodide.

Comment: It depends on the use of the solution  afterwards

Comment: Dissolving in what solvent? Are you constrained to use only water?

Answer (score 4):

Aside of dissolving iodine in ethanol, suggested in the other answer, another way is to reduce a part of iodine to iodide, e.g. by the classical reaction with thiosulphate. The rest of iodine will dissolve.

The needed amount of thiosulphate is at least 1/3 of the stoichiometric amount wrt the total iodine.

$$\ce{2 S2O3^2- + I2 -> S4O6^2- + 2 I-}$$

$$\ce{I- + I2 -> I3-}$$

As 2 mols of thiosulphate reacts with 1 mol of molecular iodine, there is needed at least 2 mol of thiosulphate per 3 mols of iodine.

$$\ce{2 Na2S2O3 + 3 I2 -> Na2S4O6 + 2 NaI3}$$

Or, if the target concentration is low enough, iodine need not iodide to dissolve itself in water.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine#Properties)

> Elemental iodine is slightly soluble in water, with one gram dissolving in 3450 ml at 20 °C and 1280 ml at 50 °C

Answer (score -1):

Dissolve it in ethanol. Iodine I2 dissolves in ethanol to give a very well known solution sometimes called "tincture of iodine"[1](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/do-iodine-dissolve-ethanol-557516)

Comment: I think prior to posting the answer it would be better to first ask OP in the comments whether changing the solvent would be a viable option for them. From the context it appears they want to use aqueous solution. Also, please don't forget to end the sentences with a full-stop (or other applicable punctuation marks depending on the situation).

Comment: HE SAID WITHOUT KI, doesnt that imply change?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please don't CAPS at anyone, this isn't polite.

Comment: Okay @andselisk im sorry, just curious, what does it mean then, does he want to dissolve it in lesser KI or what?

Comment: The way I see it OP looks for an alternative to potassium iodide to promote dissolution of iodine in water. But as I said, things that are unclear or disputable should've been sorted out in the comments first.